# There is a string which I want to split using "-" by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

CTO-Office - Production - Engineer from the given string i want to split them based on hyphen (-) but the CTO-Office should remain same.

My answer should be like :
0th Index CTO-Office,
1st Index Production,
2nd Index Engineer

`['CTO-Office', 'Production', 'Engineer']`

Answer (score 1):

As you want to split using `-` you can do so as before and after hyphen there is a blank space so your code will be like

```
let string = "CTO-office - Production - Engineer";
Const newStr = string.split(" - ") ;
Console.log(newStr);
```

Output will be like:

```
['CTO-office', 'Production', 'Engineer']
```